# Configuring JPA/Eclipselink project with Payara Server and Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, payara

I´m trying to set up a project using Payara Server Community Edition v5.2022.2, Postgresql 14 and Eclipselink.

When I test a simple rest endpoint returning a String, everything works fine, so I know that the rest configuration is working.

The problem is getting persistence to work. Every time I deploy the project to Payara and try the endpoint which will call the appropriate method to persist an entity I get an error saying no object was available for injection. I believe the problem is with the EntityManager, but I didn´t find the server.log very helpful.

These are my files.

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0"
    xsi:schemalocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="selfbookingPU"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/postgresqlpool</jta-data-source>
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation"
                value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
    version="5.0">
    <data-source>
        <name>jdbc/postgresqlpool</name>
        <class-name>org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource</class-name>
        <server-name>localhost</server-name>
        <port-number>5432</port-number>
        <database-name>selfbooking_dsv</database-name>
        <user>postgres</user>
        <password>${ALIAS=postgresql_dsv_pwd}</password>
    </data-source>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rjso.selfbooking</groupId>
    <artifactId>selfbooking</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Selfbooking App</name>
    <url>http://www.rjso.com/selfbooking</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-RC2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>selfbooking</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**APIConfig.java**

```
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class APIConfig extends Application {

}
```

**ViajanteAPI.java**

```
import entidades.Viajante;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import servicos.ViajanteServico;

@Path("/viajantes")
public class ViajanteAPI {

    @Inject
    ViajanteServico viajanteServico;

    @GET
    public void gravaViajante() {

        Viajante v = new Viajante("Rodrigo", "Oliveira", "Rodrigo J S Oliveira", "mylogin", "myemail@gmail.com");

        viajanteServico.gravaViajante(v);

    }
}
```

**Usuario.java**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

import enums.SimNaoEnum;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Inheritance;
import jakarta.persistence.InheritanceType;
import jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Usuario {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "primeiro_nome")
    private String primeiroNome;
    
    @Column(name = "ultimo_nome")
    private String ultimoNome;
    
    @Column(name = "nome_completo")
    private String nomeCompleto;
    
    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "dt_nascimento")
    private LocalDate dtNascimento;
    
    @Column(name = "ativo")
    private SimNaoEnum isAtivo;
    
    @Column(name = "bloqueado")
    private SimNaoEnum isBloqueado;

    public Usuario() {
    };

    public Usuario(String primeiroNome, String ultimoNome, String nomeCompleto, String login, String email) {
        this.primeiroNome = primeiroNome;
        this.ultimoNome = ultimoNome;
        this.nomeCompleto = nomeCompleto;
        this.login = login;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPrimeiroNome() {
        return primeiroNome;
    }

    public void setPrimeiroNome(String primeiroNome) {
        this.primeiroNome = primeiroNome;
    }

    public String getUltimoNome() {
        return ultimoNome;
    }

    public void setUltimoNome(String ultimoNome) {
        this.ultimoNome = ultimoNome;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public LocalDate getDtNascimento() {
        return dtNascimento;
    }

    public void setDtNascimento(LocalDate dtNascimento) {
        this.dtNascimento = dtNascimento;
    }

    public SimNaoEnum getIsAtivo() {
        return isAtivo;
    }

    public void setIsAtivo(SimNaoEnum isAtivo) {
        this.isAtivo = isAtivo;
    }

    public SimNaoEnum getIsBloqueado() {
        return isBloqueado;
    }

    public void setIsBloqueado(SimNaoEnum isBloqueado) {
        this.isBloqueado = isBloqueado;
    }

    public String getNomeCompleto() {
        return nomeCompleto;
    }

    public void setNomeCompleto(String nomeCompleto) {
        this.nomeCompleto = nomeCompleto;
    }

}
```

**Viajante.java**

```
import enums.SimNaoEnum;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "viajante")
public class Viajante extends Usuario {

    @Column(name = "viajante_vip")
    private SimNaoEnum isVIP;

    public Viajante() {
        super();
    };

    public Viajante(String primeiroNome, String ultimoNome, String nomeCompleto, String login, String email) {
        super(primeiroNome, ultimoNome, nomeCompleto, login, email);
    }

    public SimNaoEnum getIsVIP() {
        return isVIP;
    }

    public void setIsVIP(SimNaoEnum isVIP) {
        this.isVIP = isVIP;
    }

}
```

**RepositorioBase.java**

```
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public abstract class RepositorioBase {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

**ViajanteRepositorio.java**

```
import entidades.Viajante;

public class ViajanteRepositorio extends RepositorioBase {

    public void gravaViajante(Viajante viajante) {
        entityManager.persist(viajante);
    }
}
```

**ViajanteServico.java**

```
import entidades.Viajante;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import repositorios.ViajanteRepositorio;

public class ViajanteServico {
    
    @Inject
    ViajanteRepositorio viajanteRepositorio;
    
    public void gravaViajante(Viajante viajante) {
        viajanteRepositorio.gravaViajante(viajante);
    }

}
```

**Server.log (excerpt)**

```
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ViajanteServico,parent=ViajanteAPI,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1081564559)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:51)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:188)

MultiException stack 2 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of api.ViajanteAPI errors were found
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:224)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:334)

MultiException stack 3 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on api.ViajanteAPI
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:363)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
```

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your RepositorioBase needs to have the unitName defined in the annotation, like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "selfbookingPU")
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

Also, both your ViajanteServico and ViajanteRepositorio need to be injectable Beans, either EJB or CDI Bean. In order to do that, you need to add one of the following annotations to it: **@EJB** or **@RequestScoped** (or **@ApplicationScoped**, whatever suits your needs)

```
@EJB
public class ViajanteServico {...}

@EJB
public class ViajanteRepositorio extends RepositorioBase {...}
```